# How do you include multiple page content in one php include file?

Tags: php, html

I am wondering how would I include various elements (header, footer, nav), in one php file to be included on various pages, rather than creating multiple php files to be called separately?

In my includes file I have the following code:

```
<?php
echo '<h1 class="sub-elements">The elements for the current submission period are:<span style="font-weight:bold; color:#ff6000;"> Carnival, Residue, Maudlin</span>.</h1>';
?>
```

Outputting onto an html page that is running php I have:

```
<?php include('php-includes/current-elements.php');?>
```

Is there a way to include a particular div or class, something other than the entire file itself?

I just didnt want to create a separate php include file for every little element that i want to include on the same page.

The code below is what I had within the same include file to call a different element to be displayed on another page.

```
<?php
function elements ()
{
echo'<h1 class="sub-elements">The elements for the current submission period are:<span style="font-weight:bold; color:#ff6000;"> TESTING</span>.</h1>';
elements();
}
?>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: you can have file with several functions and call only needed ones

Comment: Since the included content is static, then why don't you just include the HTML directly? Why bother PHP-including it?

Comment: @rvighne, I am wanting to do so, as I do not want to update several pages, but just one.

Comment: What you should do is have the **static** content (like the example you have) written directly, and only the dynamic parts (like putting in variables) included using PHP. Follow Lashane's suggestion in the comments.

Comment: I created a function within the include file itself, but calling on it across various pages didn't seem to work, or the code was written incorrectly.

Comment: fyi, if your include file only has html no need to wrap it in php

Comment: The code you edited in at the bottom is nonsense – you are calling the function within itself, thereby creating an endless recursion. You have to embed the script where you define those functions once on top of your other script, and then _call_ the functions in that other script where you want the output to appear.

Comment: You can create a single PHP file that defines several functions such as `header()`, `navigation()` and `footer()`, and then you include that file in your other scripts and call those functions when needed (header and nav at the top, then you display your content and finally call footer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to avoid templates. The basic idea is to define a separate file for each of head, footer, nav and include those from your content template.

## head.php

```
<!doctype html> <html> ...
```

## nav.php

```
<body> <a href=..> page1 </a> <a href=..> page2 </a> <a href=..> page3 </a>
```

## foot.php

```
</body> </html>
```

And to create a complete page, you would do:

```
<?php
include 'head.php';
include 'nav.php'

An article about prune juice.

include 'foot.php';
?>
```

Now, if I understand correctly, you want to include only one file and be able to generate the various elements (head, nav, whathaveyou). You could do this by wrapping the include statements in functions:

## ubertemplate

```
<?php
function head() { include 'head.php'; }
function nav() { include 'nav.php'; }

function randomElement() { ?>
    An article about prune juice. <?php
}

function totalymisguideddynamiccontents() {
    echo "<div> foobar <span> moo </span></div>"
}

function() { include 'foot.php'; }
?>
```

..then in your final page, call these functions:

## uberpage

```
<?php

include 'ubertemplate.php';
?>    

<?php head() ?>
<script src=superlib.js></src>
<?php nav() ?>

Yomama so big when she wears a yellow coat people yell TAXI!. 

<?php foot() ?>
```

Finally, if I understand correctly and you think the uberpage approach seems like a good idea, ...then you should probably try it out. That may well be the only way to realize that it is flawed. I don't mean to mock your idea, but there are better ways to approach templates and the first way, the one you are trying to avoid, is cleaner (but that's only my opinion).

For a better way, look at twig templates or do some more research and find a framework that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for, albeit, for right now. I am always trying to evolve with coding; trying to learn better and efficient methods. I'm just taking this one step at a time.  I'm sure I'll come up with something better in the future and then ask myself why the heck did I ever do anything this way!?

Comment: I felt as if I could manage one, or the least amount of php files/templates would be the best, most organized way for me to handle this website. I didnt want several different templates (e.g. header, footer, nav, etc). Is there an advantage to having multiple php include files? It doesn't seem as clean to me, a php beginner, to have several php files for different page elements. If that is what you mean?

Comment: If you want everything in one file, go for it. It's just a matter of taste.