# How to change simply the content on navigation link click rather than making multiple HTML pages

Tags: php, html, css, include

I've been searching around for a good hour or so and haven't really found anything to answer my question.

The thing is, I understand how to make a page and do:

**index.php**

```
<?php
include 'head.php';
include 'nav.php';

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

But in my *nav.php*, I'm not sure how the `<a href=""></a>` works, and how to include different content pages within my *index.php* like: *contact.php*, *registration.php*, etc.

I don't know how make it so that if I were to click the "contact" navigation link for example, only the content would change, and I wouldn't have to make a whole separate HTML file like so: `<a href="bla.html">Contact</a>`

Hopefully I explained it good enough. If anyone can give me a reference or explain how to do this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you guys.

Comment: Please try in w3schools.com. It will help you and then you may try in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/

Answer (score 0):

I quoted your answer, this is the line

> I don't know how make it so that if I were to click the "contact"
>   navigation link for example, only the content would change, and I
>   wouldn't have to make a whole separate HTML file like so:
>
> ```
> <a> href="bla.html">Contact</a>
> ```

it's not the way it should be, what i get from your question is, you wanted a full page is all the same

> `<?php include 'head.php'; include 'nav.php';`
>
> and only this content should be change, not the head, not the nav, nor footer.
>
> `include 'footer.php'; ?>`

am I correct?

if it is what you wanted, you should place a php file whatever the name is, index.php would be better. and the link it self should be called with something that php can get it.

```
<a href="index.php?contact">Contact US</a>
```

and in your index.php, you also create a condition if else would be easier.

```
if($_GET['contact']){
place your html /php here
}
else if($_GET['about']){
place your html /php here
}
else{
include 'index.php';
exit();
}
```

I suggest you not to do this, everyone is now can do the code, but not the code architecture .

wish it help you to understand.

Comment: I see other people doing something like this. I may not even have explained it right. My friend gave me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122811/how-do-you-include-multiple-page-content-in-one-php-include-file as a reference. I guess it's just a way of making it more clean and not having to have multiple HTML pages. This is what I'm trying to do, I just don't understand it.

Comment: it's all the same i think. His post is right too, uhmmm i guess u new at this. i'm glad you have thing to learn, but for now do you understand about what is my post telling you about? And if you know this thing, do you know how to build function? learning it's step by step man.. don't jump out of the water u did not know, taste it first. cheers @Donavon :D

Comment: @Donavon, having multiple PHP pages is a good thing. It separates out different pieces of logic, thus reducing complexity. This is especially important as you build bigger and more complex websites. 

Also, this is way advance, but you can keep this in the back of your mind, whenever you see a website that loads part of a page super quickly, they do it by using ajax which allows them to change out part of the page instead of reloading the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different views. I believe you are looking for a way to change the view using php. One way is to add the page id in the url like `'www.myweb.com/index.php?page=contact'` and receive it as a `$_GET['page']`. I think this is the simplest way to change the view using php. And this is the `index.php`, put all the view file in the `views` folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    include 'head.php';
    include 'nav.php';
    switch($_GET["page"]){
    case 'contact':
       include 'views/contact.php';
       break;
    case 'registration':
       include 'views/registration.php';
       break;
    case 'chat':
       include 'views/chat.php';
       break;

    }
    include 'footer.php';
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

this would be your `nav.php`;

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?page=contact"> Contact </a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=registration"> registration </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I may not have explained it right. What my friend did was have a chat.php for example with only what he wanted within the chat to be on there, and he somehow linked the chat.php to his page. im not really sure how to do this

Comment: @Donavon now you just need to put the content of chat.php using html or php

Comment: Thank you! but I have a question: since it's using the same nav.php, what if I wanted to set the nav text to a certain color on the active page? how would i do that since its gonna be using the same nav.php everytime, i wouldnt be able to use "<color><ahref>"

Comment: @Donavon you can use $_GET["page"] in nav.php and change the color of the selected page